# Capture STDOUT to file with Capture::Tiny

Tags: perl

I am trying to capture STDOUT to a file with Capture::Tiny.

To give you the bigger picture, my end-goal is to:

1. run a Blender process on the command line
2. capture the log to a filehandle
3. watch the filehandle "grow"
4. pipe the content of the filehandle to a websocket for the user to watch progress via a web page

My plan is to use Capture::Tiny, and the example provided in [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/perl/comments/rbrk9m/watching_a_file_grow_in_mojoioloop_how/).

However I am stuck at step 1: I can capture STDOUT and STDERR as expected like this:

```
use IO::File;
use Capture::Tiny qw/capture/;

$\ = "\n"; $, = "\t";

my $blender = '/home/simone/blender/blender-3.1.0-linux-x64/blender -b /home/simone/some_file.blend --python /home/simone/blender_scripts/some_script.py';

my ($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = capture {
  system( $blender );
};

print join "\n", "STDOUT", $stdout =~ s/Time/Foobar/rg;
print '-' x 80;
print join "\n", "STDERR", $stderr;
print '-' x 80;
```

which produces the correct output but - as far as I can understand - does not let me watch it progress.

Doing this:

```
my $out_fh = IO::File->new("out_stdout.txt", "w+");
my $err_fh = IO::File->new("out_stderr.txt", "w+");

capture { qx/$blender/ } stdout => $out_fh, stderr => $err_fh;
```

leaves me with two empty files. Those are the two files I'd like to watch later.

How should I do this? is there a better (i.e.: workable) way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```perl
capture { qx/$blender/ } stdout => $out_fh, stderr => $err_fh;
```

should be

```perl
capture { system($blender) } stdout => $out_fh, stderr => $err_fh;
```

`qx//` causes the output to be captured, overriding the redirection created by `capture { }`.

For example,

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Capture::Tiny qw( capture );

open( my $out_fh, '>', 'out' ) or die $!;
open( my $err_fh, '>', 'err' ) or die $!;

my $cmd = <<'EOS';
perl -e'$| = 1; while ( 1 ) { CORE::say ++$i; sleep 1; }'
EOS

my $e;
capture { system($cmd); $e = $?; } stdout => $out_fh, stderr => $err_fh;

die( "Killed by signal ".( $e & 0x7F )."\n" ) if $e & 0x7F;
die( "Exited with error ".( $e >> 8 )."\n" )  if $e >> 8;
```

```
$ perl a.pl &
[1] 19051

$ cat out
1
2
3

$ cat out
1
2
3
4
5

$ kill %1
```

---

But you show yourself processing the information in the script. Capture::Tiny won't help you do that, at least not while the program is running. For that, you can use IPC::Run.

```perl
use IPC::Run qw( run );

sub do_something_with_line {
   print $_[0] =~ s/Time/Foobar/rg;
}

my $cmd = [ "perl", "-e", '$|=1; while ( 1 ) { CORE::say "Time ", ++$i; sleep 1; }' ];

my $buf = '';
run $cmd,
   '>', sub {
      $buf .= $_[0];
      while ( $buf =~ s/^(.*\n)// ) {
         do_something_with_line( $1 );
      }
   };

my $e = $?;

do_something_with_line( $buf ) if length( $buf );

die( "Killed by signal ".( $e & 0x7F )."\n" ) if $e & 0x7F;
die( "Exited with error ".( $e >> 8 )."\n" )  if $e >> 8;
```

```
$ perl b.pl
Foobar 1
Foobar 2
Foobar 3
Foobar 4
Foobar 5
^C
```

(Add `'2>', ...` to do something with stderr.)

Answer (score 1):

`system` (or `qx`) run the command to completion and then return. You need to run the command asynchronously. [IPC::Run](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run) is my preferred solution for this type of interaction.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out later. I'd be grateful if you could provide an example (especially using a FH as STDOUT), but you don't have to - the docs are a bit concise...

Comment: ikegami beat me to it. See their complete answer.